# How to Add Customer Group Name in Transactional Email (new order) on Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, email, customer-account, transactional-mail

I try to add customer group name in new order transactional email but I can't find anything about this.

I found this link : http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/transactional-emails-variable-magento/ but here it's not anything related to customer group name.

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be override some of files for add your custom variable in mail.

First copy `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php`

Create function for your requirement.
If your order data return value for customer group as `$order['customer_group']` then you have to declare function in `Order.php` file of local.

```
public function getCustomerGroup(){
 //find customer group from order customer and return it or load order model to get customer groupid.
    return $order->getCustomerGroupId();
}
```

You have to set value in System -> Transactional email -> New order template.

```
You have to set below statement in your email template.
{{var order.getCustomerGroup()}}
```

Now email template will display Customer Group value.

Set this email template from System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales email -> Order -> New Order Confirmation Template -> Save.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Then, do i have to put the only function you noted on local order.php ?

Comment: thanks. it works. i mean i recive the id, but i want the name

Comment: but i solve the problem with the namepublic function getCustomerGroup(){
     if ($groupId = $this->getCustomerGroupId()){
  $group = Mage::getModel ('customer/group')->load($groupId);
  if ($group->getId()){
   return $group->getCode();
  }
 }
 return '';
    }